# How to run qt console app without console window?

Tags: c++, qt

So how to disable console?
I trying to remove it from `.pro` file but it doesn't help at all.

`CONFIG -= console`

My goal is to run the app like background process that can be viewed in task manager not in desktop or any panels at all.

How to do that?

Comment: If run you app from Qt Creator, you have to uncheck "Run in terminal", also (Projects/Run/Working directory)

Comment: @RomhaKorev,Thanks! If i build that like exe file, would it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt Creator, you have to uncheck "Run in terminal" (checked by default when you a create a Console application project). The output will be directed to output panel but you will not be able to send inputs...

But, if you run you app outside the IDE, you just have to set `CONFIG -= console` in the .pro file.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do that in CMake?